# Rupee symbol ₹ changed to ¹ when file Added into ZIP in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, zip

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:archive/archive_io.dart' as webarc;


void writeEssay() {

  String contentString = "Essay on Rupee: ₹";

  webarc.ArchiveFile file = webarc.ArchiveFile.stream(
    "Rupee Essay.txt",
    contentString.length,
    webarc.InputStream(contentString.codeUnits),
  );

  // Add file in archive
  final webarc.Archive archive = webarc.Archive();
  archive.addFile(file);

  final webarc.OutputStream outputStream = webarc.OutputStream(
    byteOrder: webarc.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
  );

  // Encode file into Zip file
  final webarc.ZipEncoder encoder = webarc.ZipEncoder();

  final List<int>? bytes = encoder.encode(archive,
      level: webarc.Deflate.BEST_COMPRESSION, output: outputStream);

  // Download the Zip file.
  final html.Blob blob = html.Blob([bytes]);
  final String url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
  final html.AnchorElement anchor =
      html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
        ..href = url
        ..style.display = 'none'
        ..download = "Essay.zip";
  html.document.body!.children.add(anchor);

  // download
  anchor.click();
}
```

I created .txt file and in which I wrote Rupee symbol ₹ .

But when I add this txt file in ZIP file using Archive package (https://pub.dev/packages/archive) and download the zip file in flutter web, Rupee symbol changed to ¹ .

If I download .txt from flutter web it works fine. Problem arise when add this .txt file in ZIP and download the zip file.

Archive works perfect but it only changed my txt file content ₹ to ¹

How to solve this problem and keep ₹ to as it is, in ZIP file ?

I also tried to write Rupee symbol with flutter Unicode but problem is the same.

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter) [dart-zip](/questions/tagged/dart-zip) [dart-archive](/questions/tagged/dart-archive) [zip-encoding](/questions/tagged/zip-encoding) [zip-encoder](/questions/tagged/zip-encoder)

Comment: Almost certainly an encoding/decoding issue. 1) Make sure that the text file is encoded as UTF-8. 2) Ensure that the reader you're using on the unzipped text file is interpreting the file as UTF-8. 3) You could try adding a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) to the text file.

Comment: Thanks @ChuckBatson . As you said the problem was encoding. Problem solved by encoding file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

void writeEssay() {

    String contentString = "Essay on Rupee: ₹";


    // Encode your content into utf8 and then add to archive

    final List<int> encoded = utf8.encode(contentString);

    webarc.ArchiveFile file = webarc.ArchiveFile.stream(
       "Rupee Essay.txt",
       encoded.length,
       webarc.InputStream(encoded),
    );

    ........
}
```

Do not use string content directly to add into zip file.

First encode content string into UTF-8, then add that encoded List into zip. It will solve the problem.